# Laravel Model Route Not Binding Inside of Package

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I have a test in my Laravel package that looks like this:

```
public function test_that_user_can_update_menu()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $user = $this->signIn();
    $menu = factory(Menu::class)->create();

    $this->get("/menu/{$menu->id}/edit")
         ->assertStatus(200);

    $this->put(route('menu.update', $menu->id), $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Changed'
    ])->assertRedirect('/menu');

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('menus', $attributes);
}
```

The update method in my MenuController looks like this:

```
public function update(MenuRequest $request, Menu $menu)
{
    if ($menu->update($request->validated())) {
        return redirect('/menu');
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

If I dd out the $menu and actually find the Menu with id 1 it looks like this:

```
dd($menu, Menu::find(1));
```

I get this output:

```
Package\Menu\Models\Menu^ {#1180
  #fillable: array:2 [
    0 => "name"
    1 => "primary"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
Package\Menu\Models\Menu^ {#1181
  #fillable: array:2 [
    0 => "name"
    1 => "primary"
  ]
  #connection: "sqlite"
  #table: "menus"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "id" => "1"
    "name" => "Main Menu"
    "primary" => "0"
    "created_at" => "2019-08-08 11:49:23"
    "updated_at" => "2019-08-08 11:49:23"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [
    "id" => "1"
    "name" => "Main Menu"
    "primary" => "0"
    "created_at" => "2019-08-08 11:49:23"
    "updated_at" => "2019-08-08 11:49:23"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

As you can see the Route Model Binding is not finding my menu with Id 1. Am I missing something here?

Here's the route:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/menu', 'Package\Menu\Controllers\MenuController');
});
```

I don't understand why my model isn't binding. Any thoughts?

It's probably something silly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please can you post the lines involving the MenuController from the result of `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @dparoli pictures added

Comment: AFAIK the binding is correct, it should work out of the box. Do you have the same problem using the browser or it shows up only during testing?

Comment: I haven't tried in the browser yet. I'll get to the UI stuff later tonight. But it's biding on all of my methods except for update. destroy, edit, show all work fine. Something about the update method.

Comment: I take that back, it doesn't work on any of the methods. ehh oops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

In the package, it turns out there's a binding middleware that needs to be included. Here's what worked for me (at first):

```
Route::resource('/menu', 'Package\Menu\Controllers\MenuController')->middleware('bindings');
```

I noticed this by looking at the [list of middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware).

Then, after further testing, I realized that I could just use the web middleware group and set the auth to my resources inside of web as needed. This also worked for me:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::resource('/menu', 'Package\Menu\Controllers\MenuController')->middleware('auth');
});
```

I made a quick [write-up](https://kevinpimentel.com/blog/18/whys-your-laravel-package-model-route-not-binding).

In Laravel applications, the web middleware is applied to the routes/web.php file. These routes are automatically assigned the web middleware group, which provides features like session state and CSRF protection. Because I neglected this, I was missing a lot of that default web middleware functionality. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Usually i feel like there is problems with implicit binding. If you do it explicit it should work.

In `RouteServiceProvider.php`, assuming your route parameter for the id is named `menu`.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('menu', Menu::class);
}
```

Comment: In a package, what do I need to include? I tried `Illuminate\Routing\Route` but I get Route::model does not exist.

Comment: Never mind! I looked in the routing service provider. I'll just extend that in my package.

Comment: Although this didn't work, it led me down the right path. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Post the answer, it can help others in the future